# What is the best way to render LESS.js stylesheets in node.js using express?

Tags: node.js, less, express

I have a small node.js app (my first)  that I want to have compile it's less.js stylesheets when the server loads. The point I'm starting at is the express example app for jade where it appears it compiles it's SASS templates when the server is created:

```
var pub = __dirname + '/public';

var app = express.createServer(
  express.compiler({ src: pub, enable: ['sass'] }),
  express.staticProvider(pub)
);
```

I saw this and hoped it would be as simple as changing sass to less but that doesn't appear to work.

Is there a different approach I should take? Is there something I'm missing? I can't find the documentation on the .compile method anywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compile less directly. Sass does not compile to less in express. It compiles directly to css.
Same with less. It compiles directly to css.

```
var app = express.createServer(
  express.compiler({ src: pub, enable: ['less'] }),
  express.staticProvider(pub)
);
```

Comment: Hey Shripad, That's exactly what I did but it didn't compile any CSS files. I'm assuming it would put them in them in the same directory, correct?

Comment: Maybe you have an older version of Express. I suggest bumping it to 1.0.0.rc4 from whatever version you are on. Make sure to update less.js. And also check you node.js version. Lots of things break with 0.3.0. Hope you are not on that!

Comment: BAH! I figured it out. I had an import in my stylesheet that was calling a less file instead of a CSS file. Once I changed that to .css everything started working.

Comment: I have this same setup working but express is serving up stale css. If I modify the .less file and the .css file still exists, the old stale css is served statically without recompiling.  Any way to fix that?  Another annoying thing is that it takes 2 HTTP GETs to make the .css regenerate.  First one fails but does regenerate the .css so the second one succeeds.

Comment: @Peter Lyons: This is definitely weird behavior. I suggest opening an issue on the less.js/express.js github repo.

Comment: @PeterLyons - you've likely solved your issue long ago but for those visiting in the future, this is most likely a result of the order in which you are declaring your .use() statements... express.static() should be last or 2nd to last - only followed by express.errorHandler()

Comment: @busticated thanks. I've now grokked the importance of the order of middleware and things are working ideally. I think the stale .css was middleware order issue and the 2-request thing was a bug in the library that was fixed long ago.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to minify the outputted css, I found that the built in compiler (from the connect module) was missing the compress option. So rather than writing my own middleware compiler for it. I overwrote the connect less compiler in my app.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
var less;

express.compiler.compilers.less.compile = function (str, fn) {
    if (!less) less = require("less");                                                      
    try {
        less.render(str, { compress : true }, fn);
    } catch (err) {
        fn(err);
    }
};

app.use(express.compiler({ src: publicdir, enable: ['less'] }));
```

Answer (score 1):

For express 3, use the following snippet:

```
var express = require('express'),
    less = require('less');

var app = express();
app.engine('less', function (path, options, callback) {
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (error, contents) {
    if (error) return callback(error);
    less.render(contents, options, callback);
  });
});
```